# RxSpark Code execution

Tags: r, apache-spark, microsoft-r

I am trying to execute the below code with "Revo64-9.0 -f testrxspark.R" command

```
list.files(system.file("SampleData", package = "RevoScaleR"))
myHadoopCluster <- RxSpark(namenode="zzz.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com", port=8020,consoleOutput=TRUE)
rxSetComputeContext(myHadoopCluster)
file.exists(system.file("SampleData/AirlineDemoSmall.csv", package="RevoScaleR"))
bigDataDirRoot <- "/user/RevoShare" # HDFS location of the example data
rxHadoopListFiles(bigDataDirRoot) # There will be no files at this point.
source <-system.file("SampleData/AirlineDemoSmall.csv", package="RevoScaleR")
inputDir <- file.path(bigDataDirRoot,"AirlineDemoSmall")
rxHadoopMakeDir(inputDir)
rxHadoopListFiles(bigDataDirRoot)
rxHadoopCopyFromLocal(source, inputDir)
rxHadoopListFiles(inputDir)
hdfsFS <- RxHdfsFileSystem(hostName="zzz.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com", port=8020)
colInfo <- list(DayOfWeek = list(type = "factor", levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")))
airDS <- RxTextData(file = inputDir, missingValueString = "M", colInfo  = colInfo, fileSystem = hdfsFS)
# adsSummary <- rxSummary(~ArrDelay+CRSDepTime+DayOfWeek, data = airDS)
rxSummary(~ArrDelay:DayOfWeek, data = airDS)
```

I got following error:

> 17/03/19 00:00:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where appli$
>
> Warning: libjvm.so not found in /log/cloudera/parcels/MRS-9.0.1/hadoop, searching system-wide
>
> Internal Error: Cannot reset hdfs internal params while connected to an hdfs file system.
>
> Error in try({ :
>     Internal Error: Cannot reset hdfs internal params while connected to an hdfs file system.
>
> Error:  Error in try({ :
>     Internal Error: Cannot reset hdfs internal params while connected to an hdfs file system.

The ScaleR library scaleR-hadoop-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is copied to Cloudera Parcel hadoop lib folders on all nodes.
Please help me fix this at the earliest

Comment: MRS uses a directory called /var/RevoShare for its execution. Once it executes, it creates folders by the user name who executes along with its data inside this folder.

Somehow it is not deleting older files. I have manually deleted the files & then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

MRS uses a directory called /var/RevoShare for its execution. Once it executes, it creates folders by the user name who executes along with its data inside this folder.

Somehow it is not deleting older files. I have manually deleted the files & then it started working.